# Compare values excel: 2 columns with python

Tags: python, excel

i have an excel file with 2 columns:

```
     A            B
1 COLUMN 1     COLUMN 2
2 21,177.5     22,775.19
3 10,512.41    19.641.59
4 5.19         11.53
```

if value A2 >= B2: return ('OK')
else: return ('Verify')

Example output after run:

```
line 2 - 'OK'
line 3 - 'OK'
line 4 - 'Verify'
```

I am new in python and i don't how could i do this simple thing... i just know csv module, but don't works with an excel file.

Thanks.

Comment: Is Python a requirement? You can do this with Excel itself. Write `=IF($A2 >= $B2;"OK";"Verify")` in `C2` and then extend it to the whole column. If you really need Python you should export the excel data as a csv from excel itself or use a tool that can read excel files.

Comment: i do this in excel, but i don't know why in line 4 return 'ok'... in some lines return correct, but in few lines return wrong aswer...

Comment: The three results should be "Verify" according to your condition: `21177.5 >= 22775.19` = `False` so it yields "Verify". Check that cells `A2:B4` are numbers and not strings.